# String and String array Manipulation in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, pointers

I'm trying to write a string spliter function in C.It uses space as delimiter to split a given string in two or more. It more like the split funtion in Python.Here is the code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void slice_input (char *t,char **out)
{
    char *x,temp[10];
    int i,j;
    x = t;
    j=0;
    i=0;
    for (;*x!='\0';x++){
        if (*x!=' '){
            temp[i] = *x;
            i++;
        }else if(*x==' '){
            out[j] = temp;
            j++;i=0;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *out[2];
    char inp[] = "HEllo World ";

    slice_input(inp,out);
    printf("%s\n%s",out[0],out[1]);
    //printf("%d",strlen(out[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

Expeted Output:-

```
HEllo
World
```

but it is showing :-

```
World
World
```

Can you help please?

Comment: May the debugger be your friend

Answer (score 3):

`out[j] = temp;`

where `temp` is a local variable. It will go out of scope as soon as your function terminates, thus `out[j]` will point to garbage, invoking *Undefined Behavior* when being accessed.

A simple fix would be to use a 2D array for `out`, and use [`strcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) to copy the `temp` string to `out[j]`, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void slice_input(char *t, char out[2][10]) {
  char *x, temp[10];
  int i,j;
  x = t;
  j=0;
  i=0;
  for (;*x!='\0';x++) {
    if (*x!=' ') {
      temp[i] = *x;
      i++;
    } else if(*x==' ') {
      strcpy(out[j], temp);
      j++;
      i=0;
    }
  }
 }


int main()
{
  char out[2][10];
  char inp[] = "HEllo World ";

  slice_input(inp,out);
  printf("%s\n%s",out[0],out[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
HEllo
World
```

Comment: That's right but I think it would be better for OP to use strtok() soluion

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk the OP wants to implement his own `strtok()`, probably for practice.

Comment: But how this would be practice then @KrzysztofSzewczyk? =)

Comment: Good point @KrzysztofSzewczyk, but you need to practice too. :)

Comment: What do you want me to practice?

Comment: I mean in general @KrzysztofSzewczyk.

Comment: Everyone should practice.

Comment: I don't know, seems the leading way to learn C has become mindlessly staring at the screen wondering why things don't work, guess and what to change, recompile and hope, ... then repeat.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

From the website:

> char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters ); On a first
>   call, the function expects a C string as argument for str, whose first
>   character is used as the starting location to scan for tokens. In
>   subsequent calls, the function expects a null pointer and uses the
>   position right after the end of last token as the new starting
>   location for scanning.
>
> Once the terminating null character of str is found in a call to
>   strtok, all subsequent calls to this function (with a null pointer as
>   the first argument) return a null pointer.
>
> Parameters
>
> str C string to truncate. Notice that this string is modified by being
>   broken into smaller strings (tokens). Alternativelly [sic], a null
>   pointer may be specified, in which case the function continues
>   scanning where a previous successful call to the function ended.
>   delimiters C string containing the delimiter characters. These may
>   vary from one call to another. Return Value
>
> A pointer to the last token found in string. A null pointer is
>   returned if there are no tokens left to retrieve.

Example

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You can use this function to split string into tokens - there is no need to use some own functions. Your code looks like garbage, please format it.
Your source propably would look like this:

```
char *
strtok(s, delim)
    char *s;            /* string to search for tokens */
    const char *delim;  /* delimiting characters */
{
    static char *lasts;
    register int ch;

    if (s == 0)
    s = lasts;
    do {
    if ((ch = *s++) == '\0')
        return 0;
    } while (strchr(delim, ch));
    --s;
    lasts = s + strcspn(s, delim);
    if (*lasts != 0)
    *lasts++ = 0;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Actually i want to make a funtion like spilt of python, where i mention the delimiter amd it would return an array of tokens,WITHOUT USING LIBRARY FUNCTIONS.Btw thanks for your help

Comment: yeah im trying to comprehend that only...thanks for that